# PHP use namespace\class не работает в подключаемых файлах

Tags: php, ооп

У меня есть класс `Core\Router`, который нужно использовать и в index.php, и в подключаемом файле routes.php. И хотелось бы писать `use` только в index.php, но тогда пишет, что класс Router не найден в файле routes.php (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Router' not found ). Код файла routes.php:

```
<?php
Router::get('/', function () {
    echo "Hello world!";
});
```

Код файла index.php:

```
<?php
require "core/router.php";
use Core\Router;
Router::set_folder('app/views/');
require "routes.php";
```

Можно ли записывать use в один файл, чтобы он работал и в подключаемых? Потому что код работает, если я напишу use и в routes.php.

Не очень хочется повторять `use Core\Router`, если будет много файлов, которые будут использовать этот класс.

Comment: Покажите как вы неймспейс классу прописали

Comment: а в один php запихнуть а потом include

Comment: @InDevX `namespace Core;`

Comment: @Bloom вы имеете ввиду использовать класс только в index.php?

Comment: Вы должны указывать используемый класс в файле где используете

Comment: @Naumov спасибо. Я думал, что можно использовать один use для нескольких файлов (я подумал так из-за того, что в Laravel в файле routes/web.php не прописано никаких use, но класс Route находиться в каком-то пространстве имен)

Comment: есть файл boot.php в нем инклюдятся все основные классы, в том числе класс Module
потом запускается статическая функция load::module();

Comment: @Bloom спасибо за помощь

Comment: Там механизм алиасов использован https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.class-alias.php что то типа `class_alias('\Route', '\Core\Route');` и `route.php` инклудится в класс

Comment: И не советовал бы такое использовать ибо не очевидно как минимум. Лучше явно определять это проще как для понимания так и для idea

Comment: @Naumov спасибо Вам большое за помощь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простой ответ: нет, нельзя.

Но кажется, вы немного запутались. `use` нужен для того, чтобы в текущем нэймспейсе можно было использовать псевдоним имени класса. Например у вас есть нэймспейс `\` и `\Core\`, а в `\Core\` есть класс `Router`. Чтобы в `\` можно было писать просто `Router`, нужно импортировать имя, добавив `use Core\Router`. То есть `use` просто позволяет вам в начале объявить, что ниже под `Router` имеется ввиду `\Core\Router`. На мой взгляд, это довольно вредная возможность, так как она прячет от программиста бардак в нэймспейсах. Однако фичей широко пользуются, а популярные IDE автоматически добавляют `use`.

Чтобы не писать каждый раз `use Core\Router`, используйте `Router` только внутри нэймспейса `\Core`. А если он у вас глобальный, то переместите его в корневой нэймспейс `\` (уберите объявление нэймспейса в файле класса `Router`) и пишите `\Router`. Но скорее всего вам не нужен глобальный `Router`, а много файлов, использующих его, говорят об архитектурных проблемах.

- Убедитесь, что хорошо понимаете идею нэймспейсов.
- Не создавайте лишних нэймспейсов просто потому что вам нравится создавать папки.
- Обратите внимание, что в некоторых других языках программирования есть возможность объявлять классы приватными (доступными только внутри пакета). Для доступа к возможностям роутинга, возможно нужен интерфейс (фасад) `\Core\App::route()`.
- По возможности воздержитесь от глобальных состояний. Дёргать статические методы, которые создают скрытый контекст, не самый лучший способ программировать :-)

Если вы используете готовые библиотеки или фрэймворки и вам просто лень писать навязанный ими бойлерплейт (повторяющийся код, не относящийся к сути вашей задачи), то используйте IDE. Современный редактор всё напишет за вас.